# How do you use Compile Sources in Xcode 4.0?

Tags: xcode, compilation, xcode4

In Xcode 3.0, you can use Project Targets in Groups & Files panel to remove unwanted dependency files. Below is the instruction.

1. Click the arrow next to Targets until you expand it in the Groups & Files panel.
2. Click the arrow next to xauth.
3. Click Compile Sources.
4. Delete the following YAJL dependency files.

How do you do it in Xcode 4.0?

Answer (score 5):

It's very similar:

1. Select the project in the project navigator.
2. Select the Target in the detail view.
3. Select the Build Phase tab.
4. Expand the Compiled Sources section
5. Remove the file you don't want to be compiled anymore

Comment: what if you accidentally delete all the files in compile source? how do you revert that?