# [ViewController presentPopupViewController:animationType:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios

Been hitting my head over this ... I am trying to use MJViewPopupViewController and keep getting following error:

```
****-[ViewController presentPopupViewController:animationType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8016a30
2013-07-17 23:35:20.091 DesiTest[1055:c07] ****** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController presentPopupViewController:animationType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8016a30'*******
```

To keep it simple I tried to setup a small test app with just one button that when clicked would show the DetailViewController which contains a UIView with a label (very simple)

Here is my code:

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)openView: (id) sender
{
    DetailViewController *dView = [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:dView animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];

}

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController

@end
```

I would really appreciate any help.  BTW:  I am on XCode 4.6.3.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your view controller a subclass of MJViewPopupViewController ?

Comment: Hi zbMax,  No my view controller is not subclass of MJViewPopupViewController.  I just followed the author's example.

Comment: Can you pls give me a link to where you've founded this? I'd like to have a look.

Comment: What is `MJViewPopupViewController`, show the code or at least a reference.

Comment: Thanks zbMax and Wain...here is the link for reference:  https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController.  BTW:  cahn's solution worked.  thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your "Compile Sources" setting contains UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.m file.

Comment: link for reference on how to add the files:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5763073/1303176

Answer (score 0):

Cahn's suggestion worked.  Thank you!!

I added UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.m and it gave me compilation error, then I also added the "MJPopupBackgroundView.m" file.

Thanks a lot everyone :)